# How to get Cloudformtion Template out values thorugh NodeJs in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In this scenario I created Master CFT and I m getting output values (eg:SecurityGroup, VPC etc), I have to store these values in locally in Nodejs variable and i have to pass multiple CFTs later, is there any method to get all resources of the stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[describe-stacks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFormation.html#describeStacks-property) and [describe-stack-resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFormation.html#describeStackResources-property) will give you the data you need.